# smplayer doesn't show the formatting from the ass files

Tags: gnome, 13.10, fonts, video-player, mplayer

I have SMplayer on ubuntu 13.10 and it works perfectly, but when I tried to play a video with an ass file"Arabic language", it doesn't show the correct font formatting from the subtitle file,  instead all the subtitles appears in the middle of the screen with only one font.

when I tried to install VLC player and Gnome player both showed the correct formatting and font and as long as I know both smplayer and gnome player use the same bases to work (both are GUI for mplayer)so how can't smplayer show the subtitles like gnome?, so i tried to re-install Smplayer, but it doesn't solve the problem. and I searched a lot but couldn't find this problem facing someone else, and for me SMplayer is better than VLC and Gnome player.

sorry for my simple language but I am a new user to Ubuntu and don't have much technical information.

I can also put pictures to show the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem solved when I installed the libass package and updated it, then I make sure that the option of use SSA/ASS library is checked and choosed the default subtitle encoding to be UTF-8 instead of arabic, and now it works perfectly.